# Macro based on recoding does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I try to filter some dates by using a macro, in order to automatically hide older dates then "TODAY". By using the recording to find out how it works I get this:

```
Sub Datefilter()


ActiveSheet.ListObjects("diulisi").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= ">=22/2/2018", Operator:=xlOr
End Sub
```

However, I can't implement the actual date as a varibale in the code. 
I tried

```
Criteria1:=">= Range("E1").Value"
```

with E1 being the cell with the actual date but I get a syntax error.

Comment: You need to concatentate the variable with the string part of the expression: `Criteria1:=">=" & Range("E1").Value,`

Comment: Now the Syntax is ok but I get a Runtime error "9" - subscript out of range.

Comment: On the same line?

Comment: replace `ActiveSheet` by `Worksheets("your-sheet-name")` otherwise VBA takes whatever sheet is active at the moment. And make sure there is a `ListObjects("diulisi")` with the name `"diulisi"` in this sheet that has at least 2 columns